# Building Reducisaurus URLs

Tags: php, javascript, web-services, urlencode, reducisaurus

I'm trying to use [Reducisaurus Web Service](http://code.google.com/p/reducisaurus/) to minify CSS and Javascript but I've run into a problem...

Suppose I've two unminified CSS at:

```
http:/domain.com/dynamic/styles/theme.php?color=red
http:/domain.com/dynamic/styles/typography.php?font=Arial
```

According to the docs I should call the web service like this:

```
http:/reducisaurus.appspot.com/css?url=http:/domain.com/dynamic/styles/theme.php?color=red
```

And if I want to minify both CSS files at once:

```
http:/reducisaurus.appspot.com/css?url1=http:/domain.com/dynamic/styles/theme.php?color=red&url2=http:/domain.com/dynamic/styles/theme.php?color=red
```

If I wanted to specify a different number of seconds for the cache (3600 for instance) I would use:

```
http:/reducisaurus.appspot.com/css?url=http:/domain.com/dynamic/styles/theme.php?color=red&expire_urls=3600
```

And again for both CSS files at once:

```
http:/reducisaurus.appspot.com/css?url1=http:/domain.com/dynamic/styles/theme.php?color=red&url2=http:/domain.com/dynamic/styles/theme.php?color=red&expire_urls=3600
```

Now my question is, how does Reducisaurus knows how to separate the URLs I want? How does it know that `&expire_urls=3600` is not part of **my** URL? And how does it know that `&url2=...` is not a GET argument of `url1`? I'm I doing this right? Do I need to `urlencode` my URLs?

I took a peek into the source code and although my Java is very poor it seems that the [methods `acquireFromRemoteUrl()` and `getSortedParameterNames()` from the BaseServlet.java file](http://code.google.com/p/reducisaurus/source/browse/src/com/google/reducisaurus/servlets/BaseServlet.java) hold the answers to my question - if a GET argument name contains `-` or `_` they should be *ignored*?!

What about multiple `&url(n)`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to URL encode your URLs before you submit them as a parameter to another webservice.

E.g.

```
http://google.com
```

Becomes

```
http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com
```

If you do that, no special characters like ?, &, = et cetera survive the process that could confuse the webservice.

(Not quite sure what you're asking with your second question, sorry.)

Answer (score 1):

everything which starts with url is threated as a new url, so you cannot pass a parameter called url2 as a get argument of url1.

Every param name that does not contain a '-' will be treated as input.

So if you do

```
...?file1=...&url1=...&max-age=604800,
```

the max-age will not be treated as input.

However,

```
...?file1=...&url1=...&maxage=604800
```

here the maxage will be treated as input.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I though. Regarding urlencoding, is it necessary?